# Floating-point arithmetic issue when counting occurrences of values in data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a floating point arithmetic problem that does not allow me to count occurrences of values in a data.table column properly. An example:

```
> i = 0.1
> i = i + 0.05
> 
> value = c(i, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3)
> dt = data.table(value)
> dt[, .(.N), by = .(value)]
   value N
1:  0.15 1
2:  0.15 1
3:  0.20 2
4:  0.30 1
```

As you can see:

```
> i == 0.15
[1] FALSE
```

Is there an easy workaround available for me to obtain the result below? I and 0.15 are the result of a series of manipulations. Rather than trying to resolve the issue early on in the process, I would like to know whether it can be resolved during the group by counting.

```
> dt[, .(.N), by = .(value)]
   value N
1:  0.15 2
2:  0.20 2
3:  0.30 1
```

Comment: `dt[, .(.N), by = .(round(value, 16))]`?

Comment: Or just multiply by an appropriate power of 10 and use integers. If you have two decimal places, multiply by 100.

Comment: Thanks @roland, that works. I am actually very ashamed I asked this (before posting I tried the same on my real life example but got an error probably because I made a typo) :|

Comment: Don't be ashamed. You recognized that this is related to floating point arithmetics which puts you into the top one percent of R programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Roland provided the answer. I just have to `round` in the `by` statement: `dt[, .(.N), by = .(round(value, 16))]`